# What Scott 2022 e-bikes have range extenders?

Tags: electric-bike, battery

I've looked online and I *think* it's just the 'Genius' that has the range extender option.

Are there any other Scott e-bike models that have this?

Comment: This might better be served by contacting Scott directly at https://www.scott-sports.com/nz/en/company/contact or find a local dealer via https://www.scott-sports.com/nz/en/dealers/locator

Comment: Aside - every ebike has a range extender.... The rider !

Comment: They all have the option to take a bottle cage battery.  The genius just has the additional option to add the full mount plate for a standard bosch battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Scott, circa September 2022:

> The below models are Range extender compatible. Your Scott retailer will be able to talk you through these. https://www.scott-sports.com/gb/en/dealers/locator

- MTB eRIDE - Strike, Genius, Aspect, Contessa Active, Contessa Strike, Contessa Genius.
- Road - Addict eRIDE, Contessa Addict eRIDE
- Urban/All Terrain eRIDE - Axis FS, Axis men & Lady, Silence men & Lady.